# Spring Batch - duplicate Job excecutions successfully completed

Tags: java, spring, synchronization

Imagine a simple Spring Batch job, which we want to run everyday at midnight. But we have a cluster of two nodes. We want this job to run only once - so the first node who starts will finish the job and the second will skip processing.

This should be done easily, because Spring Batch holds it's state in the same database for both nodes. And it usually works, but unfortunately sometimes both nodes execute the job at the same time and finish the job. Then I can see in the database duplicate job executions (same parameters).

I think I found out why it happens - simply the job executor before starting checks if there is a job instance already in the database and if not, then creates new row. But when both checks at the same time to the database, then both find out there is nothing so both creates and runs the same execution.

We have to have the same configuration for both nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to resolve this is to make your Readers and writers as synchronized. If the code for Reader/Writer can not be changed, then implement the wrapper for synchronizing

```
public class SynchronizedItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T>
{
    private ItemReader<T> delegate;
    public void setDelegate(ItemReader<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate
    }

    public synchronized T read() {
        return delegate.read();
    }
}
```